# Set Remote for Only One Branch?

Tags: git

I need to work with a remote repository and I have it set to a local branch but I need to type the URL every time I want to update the branch from the remote repo. Is there a way to change the origin only for that one branch? So to update the branch I don't have to use the URL.

What I currently do:

```
git fetch https://github.com/username/repo branch:my-local-branch
```

But I'd rather just do something like:

```
git fetch my-local-branch
```

Where the above would fetch from `https://github.com/username/repo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`origin` is just an arbitrary name that happens to be the conventional default. But you can add as many remote repositories as you like. Just use `git remote add username https://github.com/username/repo`, then you can configure the upstream of your local branch with `git branch --set-upstream-to=username/branch my-local-branch`.

From then on you can use `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` from your `my-local-branch` or `git fetch username/branch` to fetch the remote branch from that repository.

Comment: Would it be possible to do a `git pull` without having the branch checked out? But also not having to specify the branch on remote to use (as that would already be setup with the upstream)?

Comment: Doing a `pull` without having the local branch checked out does not make much sense, does it? But if you have the local branch checked out and its upstream configured, you can of course do `git pull` and it will pull the correct branch from the correct remote. `git pull` always pulls into the currently checked out branch, as you can read in its documentation.

Comment: Well I just want the branch to be updated to the latest. There should be no conflicts or anything to change.

Comment: But you cannot pull without having the branch checked out. You can do `git fetch username/branch && git branch -f my-local-branch username/branch` though to just update the branch pointer without affecting the worktree.

Answer (score 3):

You can track a single branch from a remote server using e.g.

```
git remote add theirname git://git.theirhost.com/theirrepo.git --track theirbranch
```

Then you can `git fetch theirname` and you'll only fetch commits for `theirbranch` along with tags that refer to those commits.

If you look inside your `.git/config` file you'll see something like

```
[remote "theirname"]
url = git://git.theirhost.com/theirrepo.git
fetch = +refs/heads/theirbranch:refs/remotes/theirname/theirbranch
```

The "secret sauce" is the `fetch` reference.  Without `--track` the refspec would be `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/theirname/*`, with the `*` causing all remote branch names to be pulled across.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `git fetch <brname>`, git consults the `branch.<brname>.fetch` config variable to see which remote to fetch from. Therefore you need to:

1. Add a new remote if you do not have it already:
   `git remote add <remname> https://github.com/username/repo.git`
2. Set the config variable either by

   - editing `.git/config` manually,
   - using `git config` or
   - making your branch [track](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) the remote branch:
     `git branch -u <remname>/<brname> <brname>`
     (Note that tracking a remote branch is slightly more than pulling from it by default, which might or might not be what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

Use two branches as : **master**(by-default) and **local** (use your name as required)

```
git branch local

git checkout local
```

Now you are on local branch.Do your changes here and lastly merge it master as:

```
git merge local
```

or else directly move it your required remote

you can create **n-number** of remotes

so you can add your remote and push/pull local changes on it as :

```
git add remote add local_up <your url>

git push -u local_up master
```